# wlan0 in namespace is down

Tags: wifi

I'm trying to move wlan0 interface to separate namespace (wlan0).

```
iw phy phy0 set netns name wlan0
```

unfortunately, after such move I'm not able to bring it up.

Bellow command do nothing:

```
ip netns exec wlan0 ip link set wlan0 up
```

Some logs below:

```
# ip netns exec wlan0 ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:2f:e8:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.234/24 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ip netns exec wlan0 iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.


# dmesg | grep wlan0
[    5.481627] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    6.900705] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 3989.043318] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 6458.760215] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[332124.119807] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready


# ip netns exec wlan0 ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 linkdown
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.234 linkdown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for what you need to use Linux Network Namespaces. But it seems you are confusing the name of the namespace with the interface name **wlan0**. I get this if I try:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# iw phy phy0 set netns name wlan0
Invalid parameter: nsname(name)
Usage:  iw [options] phy <phyname> set netns { <pid> | name <nsname> }

Put this wireless device into a different network namespace:
    <pid>    - change network namespace by process id
    <nsname> - change network namespace by name from /run/netns
               or by absolute path (man ip-netns)
```

I'm wondering about you don't get this error message. It means **wlan0** isn't a valid namespace. You have first to define a namespace before you can add something to it. To not get confused and for clarification I will name my namespace `myns` and create it with:

```
rpi ~# ip netns add myns
rpi ~# ip netns list
myns
rpi ~#
```

Now I move **phy0** to the new namespace:

```
rpi ~# iw phy phy0 set netns name myns
rpi ~# iw list
rpi ~#
```

As you see there is no longer a device in the default namespace. Instead you will find it in **myns**:

```
rpi ~# ip netns exec myns iw list
Wiphy phy0
        max # scan SSIDs: 10
        max scan IEs length: 2048 bytes
[--snip--]
```

Now from that device you can manage its interface **wlan0**:

```
rpi ~# ip netns exec myns ip addr add 192.168.10.20/24 dev wlan0
rpi ~# ip netns exec myns ip link set wlan0 up
rpi ~# ip netns exec myns ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:06:e8:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.20/24 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
rpi ~# exit
exit
rpi ~$
```

This in short how to use it. As you see with `wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>` the interface is `UP`. It only does have `NO-CARRIER` so only is `state DOWN`. You have to configure *wpa_supplicant* in namespace **myns** to give the interface a carrier and set it's state UP maybe something like:

```
rpi ~$ sudo ip netns exec myns /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0
```

But I don't know because I haven't tested it. Further configuration in the Network Namespace **myns** is out of scope here because it doesn't natively belong to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I set namespace to wlan0 and put inside interface wlan0 intentionally. But as you can see on your example interface is DOWN, so you are able to reproduce issues.

Comment: @itiic I have updated my answer in the last paragraph.